# Celery Starting a Task when Other Tasks have Completed

Tags: python, django, celery

I have 3 tasks in Celery..

```
celery_app.send_task('tasks.read_cake_recipes')
celery_app.send_task('tasks.buy_ingredients')

celery_app.send_task('tasks.make_cake')
```

Both `read_cake_recipes` and `buy_ingredients` don't have any dependancies, however before the task `make_cake` can be run both `read_cake_recipes` and `buy_ingredients` need to have finished.

`make_cake` can be run at ANYTIME after the first two have started. But `make_cake` has no idea if the other tasks have completed. So if `read_cake_recipes` or `buy_ingredients` takes too long, then make_cake fails miserably.

Chaining tasks does not seem to work here because `make_cake` has more than one dependancies.

How can I still start the task `make_cake`, but have it then wait/pending etc until the other two tasks have completed first?

My saving grace is that read_cake_recipes and buy_ingredients save results to the DB, if make_cake somehow knew which ingredients or recipes to look for it could check this, maybe?

Comment: Is there any reason why `read_cake_recipes` and `buy_ingredients` are standalone tasks?  i.e., are they sometimes run without `make_cake`?

Comment: @CaseyKinsey Yes these task are sometimes run without make_cake. make_cake may never run at all. But if it does get called then it needs both of the other task results to put together and, well, make a cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally guessing at your underlying architecture, but here goes..

```
class Cake(models.Model):
    recipes_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ingredients_purchased = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    batter_prepared = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.recipes_read and self.ingredients_purchased:
            self.batter_prepared = True
        super(Cake, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


@task
read_cake_recipes():
    for cake in Cake.objects.all():
        # Read some shit!
        cake.recipes_read = True
        cake.save()

@task
buy_cake_ingredients():
    for cake in Cake.objects.all():
        # Buy some shit!
        cake.ingredients_purchased = True
        cake.save()

@task
make_cake():
    for cake in Cake.objects.filter(batter_prepared=True):
        # Make that shit!
```

Comment: This looks good. However, make_cake starts and if not ready fails (as it should) then I need Celery to keep checking i..e in this scenario if batter_prepared = true.

Comment: Again, this is just a guess at your design but I envisioned the make_cake task as running on a regular interval.

Comment: You answer really helped. Thanks. I used your checking method and added celery build in retry() this way it keeps trying until it has what it needs.