# How to start a task only when all other tasks have finished in Celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

In Celery, I want to start a task only when all the other tasks have completed. 
I found some resources like this one : [Celery Starting a Task when Other Tasks have Completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576890/celery-starting-a-task-when-other-tasks-have-completed) and 
[Running a task after all tasks have been completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308849/running-a-task-after-all-tasks-have-been-completed)
But I am quite new to celery and could not really understand the above (or many other resources for that matter).

So I have defined a task as so in a *tasks.py*:

```
@celapp.task()
def sampleFun(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # do something here
```

and I call it as this :

```
for x in xrange(4):    
   tasks.sampleFun.delay(val1, val2, val3)
```

And I assume that there would be 4 different tasks created. This actually happens as I can see the same on the web interface of *Celery Flower*.

Now what I would like to do is, have another task added. Say *finalTask* that should start only once all the above 4 tasks have completed their execution.

I also read some doc on [groups and chords in Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) but it says that if I want to do it I need to group my tasks together so they get executed in parallel. I don't want to do that. (Might be a good idea, but right now my goal is to be able to understand things. So am not really focussed on performance etc. at this point in time)

> How to do this?
>   Another more basic question which might sound rather stupid is :
>   When we say 
>   `tasks.sampleFun.delay` does it create asynchronous tasks or not ?

Comment: You need a chain with immutable signatures, see an example in the celery docs by the link you have provided. Delay does create an async task.

Comment: but in my case, the 4 in `for x in xrange(4): ` is actually dynamic. It is the number of files being uploaded, which depends on the user. Hence we do not know that before hand. I tried relating to the immutable signature examples in the [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) and it looks like to be able to do that I would need to know prior hand the number of tasks that should be there as shown in the `add.si() examples so that they all can be piped together.

Comment: You can create a list of `tasks.sampleFun.si(val1, val2, val3)` (`si` instead of `delay`) and pass that list to the `chain` function.

Comment: you mean something like this :
`my_list = []`
`for x in xrange(4):`
`my_list.append(tasks.sampleFun.si(val1, val2, val3))`
`chain(my_list)()`
?